# prestashop 1.6.1.11 category box header

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

The name (or title or header) of the category box is always changing to the chosen category. E.G., list of categories (..., **pants**, **shirts**, **suits**, ...).

If I click on shirts the header of the category box also changes to shirts instead of sticking to categories. I don't want this.

I want the header of the category box to be fixed to the name **categories**.

And if possible I want to have **categories** exchanged with **Product Groups**.

Answer (score 0):

You must edit '\themes\your-theme-folder\header.tpl'. Change `<title>` tag like this:

```
<title>{if $page_name=='category'}{l s='Product Groups'}{else}{$meta_title|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}</title>
```

Good luck.